# Does using random plus addressing (gmail) fix GHub's spoofed content security hole?

Tags: git, email, github, security, web

Problem: I can't have my username and profile pic associated with spoofed content throughout the duration of my account, just by signing up to Ghub.

Github the social media, allows you to set the committer and author's email addresses to anything whatsoever without verification.

This means that I can use a secure laptop, make a secure TLS connection to github.com (a Fortune-13 org) and have the webpage reasonably[1] claiming fake content as real (eg [eb309323](https://github.com/search?q=eb309323)).

Question: What can be done to prevent this security risk other than deleting my GH acc? Is changing my email address to `foobar+bigrando12X4Z037j02uL84` @gmail.com basically all that I need to do?

---

• I know enabling `Partially Verified` will [heighten the security risk](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/GH-logic-whytFK-does-upgrading-to-vigilant-mode-allow-Malfoy-to-change-a-commit-from-noicon-default-to-Partially-Verified-sec-https-jsfiddle-net-gw29rsbe), but I have it disabled.


<sub>• [1]: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus</sub>

Comment: Your "heighten the security risk" claim links a quora question with no answers, linking a random paragraph on a third site. No unverified attribution is going to be relied on by anyone sane as security for anything, so you're going to have to explain what exact security you're claiming is being risked here. "I can summon spirits from the vasty deep"… "So can I, and so can any man. The question is: will they come?". If there's some consequential problem here, please explain it, [Someone is *wrong* on the Internet](https://xkcd.com/386/) isn't going to clear that bar.

Comment: @jthill, ? Kindly take your quora frustrations elsewhere, not here downvoting questions based on your views of Quora. Btw the domain is irrelevant  as the snippet is merely informative. Ie, I know the sky is blue; how does it matter that it's on quora? (I know enabling Partially Verified will heighten the security risk, but I have it disabled.)

Kindly click on that link to vent your frustrations there.

Answer (score 1):

It is by design that anyone can upload arbitrary commits with an arbitrary email to a repository, because many projects use a patch-based workflow.  For example, I contribute to Git, and since every patch is applied without a signature to the repository by the maintainer.  This is not in any way a security hole.

Changing the email address doesn't affect this in any way, since anyone can simply find a repository with one of your commits, copy the email address, and push a commit.

If you want to require authenticity for commits, then you need to digitally sign them and enable vigilant mode.  There's no alternative to signing every commit and tag if you want to prevent spoofing in Git repositories in general.